# How to close mobile menu on click for anchor links

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need a help with mobile menu. I try to find/add some script which close menu after click on menu item. Can anybody help with.

My page is https://www.institut-vz.si/

So When you click on the menu link it's going to the section but the menu is still open. So I need some script it should close after clicking the menu link.

When you click on burger menu, "style" change from display:none to display:block, and menu item get class "inView current_page_item".

Any help please.

```
<nav id="main-menu" class="menu-header-menu-container">
<ul class="menu menu-toggle-open" style="display: block; overflow: visible;">
    <li id="menu-item-16670" class="menu-item"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16673" class="menu-item  inView current_page_item"><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16676" class="menu-item"><a href="#aboutus">About us</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-16677" class="menu-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also mobile menu have this active JS code:

```
//Mobile Menu
$("#dt-menu-toggle").click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();

    var $menu = $("nav#main-menu").find("ul.menu:first");
    $menu.slideToggle(function(){
        $menu.css('overflow' , 'visible');
        $menu.toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
    });

    var $right = $("nav#main-menu").find("ul.menu-right");
    if( $right.length ) {
        $right.slideToggle(function(){
            $right.css('overflow' , 'visible');
            $right.toggleClass('menu-toggle-open');
        });    
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in footer.php

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".menu-item", function(){

    jQuery(".menu-item").closest(".menu").removeClass("menu-toggle-open").hide();
});
```

Comment: I added, but not work. 
I think the problem is with style "display:block". How to get back to display:none when someone click on menu item.

Comment: And I also see that this script doesn't remove class "menu-toogle-open" after click on menu item.

Comment: you need to add this `jQuery(".menu-item").closest(".menu").removeClass("menu-toggle-open").hide();` script in `custom.js` at line number 160

Comment: Not :/ I tried to put before and after line 160, and not work. Hmmm

Comment: I found solution:
    $('#main-menu ul li a').click(function(){
    $("nav#main-menu ul").css('display' , 'none');
    $("nav#main-menu ul"). removeClass('menu-toggle-open');
    });